# Apex Process exited before completing request when with Golang

Tags: mysql, go, aws-lambda

All the answers for something like this are in Javascript, and I'm not sure if it applies in Go.

I've done this

```
func main() {
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "db_details")
  err = db.Ping()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to prepare connection to database")
    // log.Fatal("Error:", err.Error())
  }
    apex.HandleFunc(func(event json.RawMessage, ctx *apex.Context) (interface{}, error) {
      fmt.Println(ctx)
      return map[string]string{"hello": "world"}, nil
    })
}
```

So I'm trying to hit my Amazon RDS MySql db using golang's sql driver.

I get this error

```
Error: function response: Response Id: <some_id> Process exited before completing request
```

From looking around, there are two causes - 1. I need Go's equivalent of `context.done`, or 2. I need to raise the timeout.

As I'm using Apex, I raised the timeout to be 300s, which is the maximum. No luck there.

I then tried going through the Apex code to see if there was a `Context.Done` defined or used anywhere - there isn't.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Not familiar with Apex - does `HandleFunc` return immediately? If so, your program exits right after, which might explain the error.

Comment: From apex docs "you must use stderr for logging" fmt.Println would print to Stdout by default. Maybe that is the issue? Have no knowledge of apex or how you run this :)